# why the AdoNetAppender isnt writing log messages to the DB?

Tags: c#, .net, log4net

I am using the AdoNetAppender
and here is a portion of my config file:

```xml
 <appender name="ADONetAppender" type="log4net.Appender.ADONetAppender">
  <bufferSize value="1" /> 
  <connectionType value="System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection, System.Data, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
  <connectionString value="[we will set this automatically at runtime]" />
  <commandText value="INSERT INTO Log ([Date],[Thread],[Level],[Logger],[Message],[Exception]) VALUES (@log_date, @thread, @log_level, @logger, @message, @exception)" />
   <parameter>
    <parameterName value="@log_date"/> <dbType value="DateTime"/> <layout type="log4net.Layout.RawTimeStampLayout"/>
  </parameter>
       <parameter>
    <parameterName value="@thread"/> <dbType value="String"/> <size value="255"/> <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%thread"/>
    </layout>
  </parameter>
  <parameter>
     <parameterName value="@log_level"/> <dbType value="String"/> <size value="50"/> <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%level"/>
    </layout>
  </parameter>
   <parameter>
     <parameterName value="@logger"/> <dbType value="String"/> <size value="255"/> <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%logger"/>
    </layout>
  </parameter>
   <parameter>
     <parameterName value="@message"/> <dbType value="String"/> <size value="4000"/> <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%message"/>
    </layout>
  </parameter>
   <parameter>
     <parameterName value="@exception"/> <dbType value="String"/> <size value="2000"/> <layout type="log4net.Layout.ExceptionLayout"/>
  </parameter>
</appender>
```

and this is my code to log messages:

```
 private static readonly ILog fifthlog = LogManager.GetLogger("ADONetAppender"); fifthlog.Info("this is db log");
```

I'm also using other appenders like RollingFileAppender, and they are working perfectly but this one doesn't, because when I do this query `select * from Log` in my sql server the table is empty. My db connection is successful because I tested the connection. What's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to really find out what is happening you should enable internal debugging:

http://log4net.sourceforge.net/release/1.2.0.30316/doc/manual/faq.html#internalDebug

A few things that come to my mind:

- Permission issue on the database (as pointed out by *devstuff* already)
- If you use integrated security: It could be that you connect with the caller instead of the host process (this happens for instance if you have a sharepoint environment).
- Conversion problem with one of your parameters (though this seems unlikely)

Comment: thnx i got it fixed it was the connection and permissions

Answer (score 0):

Does the account have insert permissions on the `Log` table?

And what is the configured output level for this appender?